# How to hide some fields when transforming XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I am using XSLT for the first time and finally got it to work; but I don't want to show all the XML data in my final input...  I only want to see what's in the table in the XSLT stylesheet. Can anyone help to advise how I can limit the output to just that?

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-infoPathSolution name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:QBA--Quote-Below-Authority:-myXSD-2012-12-05T14-55-38" solutionVersion="1.0.0.492" productVersion="14.0.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="http://team.apmoller.net/sites/NNP-One-Stop-Shop/QBA%20Quote%20Below%20Authority/Forms/template.xsn"?>
<?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?>
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:ma="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/metadata/properties/metaAttributes" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields" xmlns:q="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/queryFields" xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution" xmlns:dms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/documentManagement/types" xmlns:tns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService" xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-12-05T14:55:38" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-US">
    <my:Requestor>VRO009</my:Requestor>
    <my:DecisionMaker>0</my:DecisionMaker>
    <my:QBARateStructure></my:QBARateStructure>
    <my:ClusterReviewer></my:ClusterReviewer>
    <my:ClusterReviewDate xsi:nil="true"></my:ClusterReviewDate>
    <my:QBA-Request-Table>
        <my:QBA-Request>
            <my:Origin>zeebrugge</my:Origin>
            <my:Destination>chennai</my:Destination>
            <my:EquType>Dry</my:EquType>
            <my:EquSize>20</my:EquSize>
            <my:Weight>22</my:Weight>
            <my:TargetWeeklyVolume>10</my:TargetWeeklyVolume>
            <my:CommitmentReqd>No</my:CommitmentReqd>
            <my:CurrentAllin>1000</my:CurrentAllin>
            <my:RequestedAllin>125</my:RequestedAllin>
            <my:RequestedCY>1310</my:RequestedCY>
            <my:CompetitionAllin>125</my:CompetitionAllin>
            <my:CentreTNMLineAction></my:CentreTNMLineAction>
            <my:CentreTNMLineCounter></my:CentreTNMLineCounter>
        </my:QBA-Request>
        <my:QBA-Request>
            <my:Origin>zeebrugge</my:Origin>
            <my:Destination>chennai</my:Destination>
            <my:EquType>Dry</my:EquType>
            <my:EquSize>20</my:EquSize>
            <my:Weight>22</my:Weight>
            <my:TargetWeeklyVolume>10</my:TargetWeeklyVolume>
            <my:CommitmentReqd>No</my:CommitmentReqd>
            <my:CurrentAllin>1000</my:CurrentAllin>
            <my:RequestedAllin>125</my:RequestedAllin>
            <my:RequestedCY>1310</my:RequestedCY>
            <my:CompetitionAllin>125</my:CompetitionAllin>
            <my:CentreTNMLineAction></my:CentreTNMLineAction>
            <my:CentreTNMLineCounter></my:CentreTNMLineCounter>
        </my:QBA-Request>
        <my:QBA-Request>
            <my:Origin>zeebrugge</my:Origin>
            <my:Destination>chennai</my:Destination>
            <my:EquType>Dry</my:EquType>
            <my:EquSize>20</my:EquSize>
            <my:Weight>22</my:Weight>
            <my:TargetWeeklyVolume>10</my:TargetWeeklyVolume>
            <my:CommitmentReqd>No</my:CommitmentReqd>
            <my:CurrentAllin>1000</my:CurrentAllin>
            <my:RequestedAllin>125</my:RequestedAllin>
            <my:RequestedCY>1310</my:RequestedCY>
            <my:CompetitionAllin>125</my:CompetitionAllin>
            <my:CentreTNMLineAction></my:CentreTNMLineAction>
            <my:CentreTNMLineCounter></my:CentreTNMLineCounter>
        </my:QBA-Request>
    </my:QBA-Request-Table>
    <my:FormCountry>Belgium</my:FormCountry>
    <my:AccessLevel>Cluster</my:AccessLevel>
    <my:CentreReviewer></my:CentreReviewer>
    <my:CentreReviewDate xsi:nil="true"></my:CentreReviewDate>
    <my:group1></my:group1>
    <my:Filename>QBA2013-06-06T13:59:18VRO009</my:Filename>
    <my:Engine>New</my:Engine>
</my:myFields>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-12-05T14:55:38">
<xsl:template match="my:myFields/my:QBA-Request-Table">
    <h2>Request Lines</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Origin</th>
        <th>Destination</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="my:QBA-Request">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="my:Origin" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="my:Destination" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
moijoNoBCOT1T2E2001-01-01231789Artichokes, non-frozen, vegetablesBoeger, AndrewCRB\abo055User
**Request Lines   
Origin Destination 
1 2 
1 3 
1 4** ***(this in bold is all formatted as per the table nicely)***
*AllClusterabo0550QBA2013-06-06T15:43:21abo055NewCRB\ABO055trueMaersk LineiojYesiojjWARNING: You have selected the "Test" trade, which is meant for form testing only. If you leave this as-is, no one in CENTNM will ever review your request.true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) will process all elements other than the ones you have specifically matched, so you need to write a template for the root node and take everything under control.

In addition it is better to replace `for-each` with templates wherever possible, and it tidies your output up a lot if you exclude the unwanted namespace prefix `my` from the output, and specify HTML output with indentation.

This stylesheet demonstrates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-12-05T14:55:38"
    exclude-result-prefixes="my">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="my:myFields/my:QBA-Request-Table"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="my:QBA-Request-Table">
    <h2>Request Lines</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Origin</th>
        <th>Destination</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="my:QBA-Request"/> 
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="my:QBA-Request">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="my:Origin" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="my:Destination" /></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<h2>Request Lines</h2>
<table border="1">
   <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Origin</th>
      <th>Destination</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>zeebrugge</td>
      <td>chennai</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>zeebrugge</td>
      <td>chennai</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>zeebrugge</td>
      <td>chennai</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```